# How to find the value of an unknown mathematical variable in a function Using Java

Tags: java, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to solve a mathematical problem that is in the form of this function:

f(x) = c<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + q<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + q<sub>2</sub>x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + q<sub>3</sub>x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Now I have created an interface where the user can input the values of c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>, and q<sub>3</sub>

Now what we need to solve this function are the values of x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> to be substituted in the equation.
In other parts of the algorithm, the values of x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> usually ends up with something like x<sub>1</sub> = (0 - 0.8ρ<sub>1</sub>) and x<sub>2</sub> = (0 - 0.6ρ<sub>1</sub>)

Now assuming the user keyed in the values of c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, q<sub>1</sub>, q<sub>2</sub>, and q<sub>3</sub> as 0, 2, -1, 2 and -2 respectively, this will make the function to appear as:

f(x) = 0x<sub>1</sub> + 2x<sub>2</sub> + -1x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + -2x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

This can be re-written as:

f(x) = 2x<sub>2</sub> - 1x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + 2x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> - 2x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Now if we substitute x<sub>1</sub> = (0 - 0.8ρ<sub>1</sub>) and x<sub>2</sub> = (0 - 0.6ρ<sub>1</sub>) in the equation above we will have:

f(x) = 2(0 - 0.6ρ<sub>1</sub>) - 1(0 - 0.8ρ<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + 2(0 - 0.8ρ<sub>1</sub>)(0 - 0.6ρ<sub>1</sub>) - 2(0 - 0.6ρ<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup>

As you can see if we solve further we will eventually find the value of ρ<sub>1</sub>

So the problem now is how can one write a program to solve this kind of problem and get the value of ρ<sub>1</sub>
 in Java, or is there such a program already written?
I've tried so many things already but can't come up with a solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

- Jevison

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to finish developping f(x) so it gets to the form ax^2 + bx + c = 0

and then use this to solve: http://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Algebra_Polynomials_Second_Degree.aspx

It's not really a Java problem. Once you have the equations for the solution, it'll be easy to write.

Comment: ax^2 + bx + c = 0 is a cubic function, I'm working on a quadratic function.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this isn't quadratic... f(x) = 2(0 - 0.6ρ1) - 1(0 - 0.8ρ1)2 + 2(0 - 0.8ρ1)(0 - 0.6ρ1) - 2(0 - 0.6ρ1)2. You need to develop this further.